# Integer prototype

Tags: javascript

how can you make an prototype on an Integer?

```
Integer.prototype.num = function(dec){
    return number_format(this.toString(), dec);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript has only `Number`. Extending the prototype of built in objects is not a good idea in general

Comment: it is called 'monkey patching' and is considered bad practice

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's no `Integer` in JavaScript, just `Number`. You can extend `Number` in the way you've shown.

There are two camps with regard to extending the built-in prototypes. One camp says it's evil and you must not do it; use a separate function you pass the object into. The other camp says this is exactly why we have prototypes, so that we can extend the functionality of things as we see fit.

If you're in the second camp, there are pitfalls to avoid:

- Never, ever, *ever* extend `Object.prototype` in the way you've shown (by assignment). You'll break a huge amount of code.
- Be very, very wary of extending `Array.prototype` in the way you've shown, you'll break a fair bit of code.

The reason in both cases is that when you extend a prototype in that way, you create an *enumerable* property on the prototype. That means it shows up in `for..in` loops. Custom and practice in the JavaScript world is that there **must** be no enumerable properties on a blank object (`{}`). Arrays may be more acceptable, but beware people who don't really understand [what `for..in` does](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) who think it will loop through the array indexes; if you extend `Array.prototype` in the way you've shown, you'll break their loops. (I would argue their loops were already broken, but leave that to the side...)

I keep saying "in the way shown" because you can add *non-enumerable* properties to objects via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.defineproperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "num", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() { ... }
});
```

Note that `enumerable: false` (`false` is the default for `enumerable`; I'm being explicit here for emphasis). That means it doesn't show up on `for..in` loops, and so softens that argument against extending prototypes of native objects.

However, the possibility of naming conflicts (with other code also extending the prototype, or features added in future versions of JavaScript) remains, even with `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: I'm in the second camp and always have been since the language was first invented. However, thank you for clarifying that point. I always wondered why prototyping didn't work for Object objects and was considered a bad idea for other objects. Very nicely explained.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript has no integral types (`Integer`). Only floating point numbers (try `typeof 3`. Returns `Number`).

So you could use something like:

```
Number.prototype.myfunc = function() { }
```

#### Addendum

As Felix Kling mentioned in the comment, extending Javascript built in objects using the `.prototype` property is usually *not* a good idea. The new extension applies automatically to *all* objects of this type - including those already instantiated and the nones that will be created by code other than yours. Thus, it might interfere with what some other code is expecting of the Number object.

Comment: No, it works fine without constructor: `Number.prototype.myfunc = function() {console.log(42)}; a = 5;a.myfunc() // 42`. Actually using `Number()` will create all kinds of other problems.

Comment: You do not need to use the constructor to be able to use `Number` methods. `(10).toString()`

Comment: @Felix and CD: Corrected. Sorry about this one and thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5):

`Integer` is not a native javascript Object. Maybe you mean adding a formatting method to the prototype of `Number`? *For example*:

```
var formatNum = function(format){
   return format === 'dec2'
           ? this.toPrecision(String(this).length+2)
           : format === 'div10'
           ? Number(this/10).toPrecision(2)
           : this;
}
Number.prototype.format = formatNum;
var num = 22;
num.format('dec2'); //=> 22.00
num.format('div10'); //=> 2.2
```